# how to bind image src path to backend data in vue js

Tags: image, vue.js, frontend, backend

How to bind image src path to backend data in Vue js
I know how to do it in frontend it is like

`` <img :src="require(`@/assets/${item.image}`) ``

how can I do it with backend data

Comment: What does this backend data look like?

Comment: it is json {
            "id": 1,
            "meta": {
                "type": "wagtailimages.Image",
                "detail_url": "http://localhost/api/v2/images/1/",
                "tags": [],
                "download_url": "/media/original_images/1_3.png"
            },
            "title": "iphone.png"
        }

Answer (score 0):

if you are after of the download URL:

```
<img :src="require(`@/assets/${item.image}`).download_url"
```